# Is it possible to issue a failure to an AngularJS post request, with a Golang server?

Tags: angularjs, go

I have a HTTP server written in golang and the client is written in AngularJs. The client will send a POST request to the server with username/password to attempt to register a new account. I want the client to do something depending on the answer of the server. If a user with the requested username already exists I want to stay at the registration site, else I want the client to change the view to something else.

I have the follow code to POST to the server, but how do I tell the client that the request failed?

```
$scope.register = function(){
    var postBody = JSON.stringify({username:$scope.vm.user.username, password:$scope.vm.user.password})

    Registration.save(postBody, function(data){
        //on success
        console.log(data)
        //$location.path('/bookingsystem')
    });     
};
```

Comment: You can consider to use http status codes (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), eg, `302` for redirection, `201` for created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using $resource to create `Registration` you can do

```
Registration.save(postBody, function(data, responseHeaders){
    //on success
    console.log(data)
    console.log(responseHeaders)
    //$location.path('/bookingsystem')
}, function(httpResponse){
    // Handle the error
    console.log(httpResponse)
});
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) on $resource for more API documentation.

Comment: Yea I use $resource.  I added on the server side http status code that ch33hau mentioned and handled it in the client by checking the status code.